# Control Vertical Alignment of Text In Title Container for Tableau Dashboards

Tags: containers, dashboard, tableau-desktop

I'm unable to reproduce forcing the text in the title container to be in the upper left hand corner. I can only control the horizontal alignment. Have any of you run into this?

Download the workbook from https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/googlebicert/viz/GoogleBusinessIntelligenceCertificateMetroDashboardwithEdits/MinnesotaInterstateTrafficVolume

Do a Reset on the Title by selecting Reset Title from the options menu of the Title Container and  "Minnesota Interstate Traffic Volume" will drop into the middle of the container. How would you go about moving that text back to the top left of the container without pressing undo?

The only alignment setting that I can control is horizontal which works, but vertical alignment seems to be a different issue.